# LazyColumn reverseLayout not scrolling with talkback

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

Consider this:

```
val items = List(100) { "Item at: $it" }

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    reverseLayout = true,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
) {
    items.forEach {
      item { Text(it, color = Color.White) }
    }
}
```

Using Talkback, the initial focus is the item at the very top (Even though tbh where reverseLayout is set to true, feels like it should start at item 0), but that can still be achieved by use a `FocusRequester`. However the problem is when you move back a step in Talkback. Instead of scrolling up to item 24, it focuses item 0 and this just loops between these items and you cannot scroll beyond item 23 automatically by going previous/next in Talkack

[image: Talkback initial focus]

Comment: This looks like a bug, report it to [compose issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bug, you can track the status here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/19977047